# Python: int(3.0) = 2

Tags: python, floating-point, int

Observe the following python program

```
def goo(y,x):
    y = float(y)
    x = float(x)
    yup = (y - x - 1) / x
    yup = str(yup)
    yup = yup.split(".")
    decimal = "." + yup[1]
    decimal = float(decimal)
    output = decimal / (1/x)

    print output
    print int(output)

goo(9,5)
```

When the program executes "print output" the answer is 3.0

When the program executes "print int(output)" the answer is 2

"print int(output)" should execute to deliver 3, not 2

Why is this happening?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  This is important since the semantics of `/` are different between the two by default.

Comment: @Makoto obviously Python 2, judging by the lack of `()` in the `print`.

Comment: This is python 2.7 using the Pythonista app on ios

Comment: Floats can't be exactly represented in computers.

Comment: I don't see why that should matter. Variable "output" is equal to 3.0. When it becomes int(3.0) it equals 2 which is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The default for the `print` statement is to round the value to the nearest. `int()` truncates.

```
>>> print 2.99999999999999
3.0
>>> print int(2.99999999999999)
2
```

If you want to see a more exact representation, use `repr`.

```
>>> print repr(2.9999999999999)
2.9999999999999
```

Comment: Ah I see. I had no idea print rounds things. Thanks!